# How to return filtered result set in Marklogic?

Tags: xml, search, xquery, marklogic

Consider the following xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Now I want to run a search query against this document and want to return a filtered result set (e.g. author name).

One way to do this is:-

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" 
at "/Marklogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options:=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<transform-results apply="raw"/>
</options>;

for $x in search:search("", $options)/search:result
return $x//author/text()
```

But `search:search` API is first caching the whole result in its cache and then we are finding our desired node with **xpath**.  I don't want this.  I want `search:search` API to return only the desired element so that whole result set is not cached in `marklogic` server. Can anybody tell me please how can I achieve this in `Marklogic` ?

Comment: In MarkLogic, the term 'filtered' means something different than your use here.

Comment: Are your XML documents all about the same size as the sample you have above or does a single <catalog> contain many <book> tags?  If the <catalog> file is large, perhaps you can split it up into individual XML files per <book>?  In this case, why do you feel that you need a search instead of just an XPath like //author/title() ? Aside from paging, I'm not sure what search:search() is doing for you in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `search:search` function doesn't really have a cache of its own, as far as I am aware. You might be happier using `search:parse` and `search:resolve-nodes` instead, but the XQuery evaluator will still bring the XML into memory in order to extract the author text.

Getting further away from the search API, you could create a range index on `author` and use `cts:element-values` to get its values directly from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Puneet, if you're using MarkLogic version 5.0, you can configure something called a "metadata snippet" to get just the elements you want *instead* of the default snippets.

Here's an example configuration:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <transform-results  apply="metadata-snippet">
        <preferred-elements>
            <element name='ordinal' ns='http://marklogic.com/ns'/>
        </preferred-elements>
    </transform-results>
</options>
```

And another:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <transform-results  apply="metadata-snippet">
        <preferred-elements>
            <element name='author' ns=''/>
            <element name='title' ns=''/>
        </preferred-elements>
    </transform-results>
</options>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Cts:search instead of search:search if you want very slim result.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" 
 at "/Marklogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

  declare variable $options:=
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
     <grammar xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
      <quotation>"</quotation>
       <implicit>
     <cts:and-query strength="20" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"/>
      </implicit>
     <starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</starter>
      <starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">- </starter>
  <joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" 
  tokenize="word">OR</joiner>
 <joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" 
  tokenize="word">AND</joiner>
 <joiner strength="30" apply="infix" element="cts:near-query" 
  tokenize="word">NEAR</joiner>
 <joiner strength="30" apply="near2" element="cts:near-query">NEAR/</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LT"
  tokenize="word">LT</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LE" 
  tokenize="word">LE</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GT" 
  tokenize="word">GT</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GE" 
  tokenize="word">GE</joiner>
 <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="NE" 
  tokenize="word">NE</joiner>
       </grammar>
       <transform-results apply="raw"/>
    </options>;

 let $query := cts:query(cts:parse("in-depth look",$options))
  let $searchresult := cts:search(fn:doc()//book,$query)
  for $each in $searchresult 
    return $each/author
```

This will give you a slim result than the Search:search one should avoid using search:search and go through this route. this give much more flexibility and also slim result set.